# How can I tell if my QAction has been triggered with a shortcut?

Tags: qt, kde-plasma

I have a QAction in my code which is linked to a a toolbar button and a shortcut. This QAction is used for setting the focus and displaying a Filter bar widget. The QAction requires special event handling when invoked by a shortcut so the focus will be set on my Filter bar widget. Whereas, if triggered with the toolbar button, the Filter bar's visibility will be toggled.

My QAction is:

```
QAction* showFilterBar = actionCollection()->addAction("show_filter_bar");
showFilterBar->setText(i18nc("@action:inmenu Tools", "Filter"));
showFilterBar->setToolTip(i18nc("@info", "Toggle the Filter Bar"));
showFilterBar->setIcon(QIcon::fromTheme("view-filter"));
showFilterBar->setCheckable(true);
actionCollection()->setDefaultShortcut(showFilterBar, Qt::CTRL | Qt::Key_I);
connect(showFilterBar, &QAction::triggered, this, &DolphinMainWindow::toggleFilterBar);
```

And the code for my toggleFilterBar function is:

```
void DolphinMainWindow::toggleFilterBar()
{
    m_activeViewContainer->setFilterBarVisible(!m_activeViewContainer->filterBarHasFocus());
    updateViewActions();
}
```

Hence, my problem is, I need to figure out if the QAction was invoked by pressing the ToolBar button or if it was invoked by a shortcut. How can I find this out?

Answer (score 1):

Make a separate slot for the shortcut for the QAction shortcut keys (it will be unique). ex:

```
new QShortcut(QKeySequence( Qt::CTRL + Qt::Key_I),
                  this, SLOT(slotshowFilterBarShortCut()));
```

so shortCut trigger will be called separately.normal action trigger will be called in separate slot.